# After Feathers authenticate('jwt') user is authenticated but req.user is an empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I'm trying to authenticate user with `authenticate('jwt')` and user is in fact authenticated `req.authenticated` returns `true` but the `req.user` is an empty Object. I'm thinking `entity` config isn't right since it tries to populate something but doesnt figure out which entity to use. I'm actually puzzled as to what is an `entity` in feathers context. File name in `*.model.js` ? Class inside that file?

If it's relevant, I'm doing authentication with JWT cookie enabled. (If I remove it, it shows 401 Unauthorized) so I'm sure that works.

I've tried couple other suggestions people gave to similar question but none worked so far.

Comment: Please show your code in the question. Otherwise, it would be very hard to find the root cause of the problem.